# Why can't I retain a UIView-Pointer?

Tags: iphone, uiview, retain

I'm trying to pass a UIView to another class - which kinda works, but I can't retain the pointer...

in my .h file I declare the view:

```
UIView *someView;
```

I add the property

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *someView;
```

And in the .m-file I synthesize the property

```
@synthesize someView;
```

Then I have a method to set the view (which is set in the .h file as well - believe me :):

```
-(void)makeViewPointer:(UIView *)myView{
    someView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    someView = myView;

    for(UIView *aView in someView.subviews){

        NSLog(@"tag %d", aView.tag);

    }
}
```

So far, everything's working. When I log the someView, I get a pointer and all the subviews are accessable.

I'm calling this method from another class - which seems to work fine.

NOW - I have an IBAction set up to do something with that view after a button is clicked

```
-(IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"show the view %@", someView);

    for(UIView *aView in someView.subviews){  // doesn't output anything

        NSLog(@"tag %d", aView.tag);

    }

}
```

At this point, the someView-var is empty again - WHY????

I assumed, that when I use @property (nonatomic, retain), the variable gets retained automatically?

I also tried to retain the variable upon initializing:

```
someView = [[UIView alloc] retain];
```

doesn't work

or

```
someView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[someView retain];
```

doesn't work either...

What on earth am I doing wrong???

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Few things.

```
someView = [[UIView alloc] init];
someView = myView;
```

The above is wrong. First you're creating a new `UIView` instance and assigning it to `someView`. You then assign `myView` to `someView`. This is causing a memory leak, because you never released `someView`, you just reassigned it.

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
[someView release];
someView = [myView retain];
```

You then have to make sure you release `someView` when you're completely finished with it.

This is what the `@property (nonatomic, retain)` will do, but to use that you have to do:

```
[self setSomeView:myView];
```

Comment: Thanks Tom - this does make sense... however - it ain't working...

I use: 

-(void)makeViewPointer:(UIView *)myView{
 
    [self setSomeView:myView]; 
}

but on the next call to «someView» - it's empty again... ???

Damn

Comment: Are you sure the class is being retained?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the self-dot notation then you don't retain the object assigned to the property.

You need to use:

```
self.someView = myView;
```

and

```
for(UIView *aView in self.someView.subviews){
```

The self notation calls the synthesized accessor methods that manage retention. If you don't use self, nothing is retained properly.

Comment: Thanks TechZen...

Tried that - but it ain't working...

I forgot to mention that I tried the self-dot-notation already...

That's weird...

Comment: You might try posting your actual code. It's probably a detail amiss somewhere. There's no reason for what your trying to do not to work.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I guess, I did everything as wrong as possible ;)

I should've mentioned, I guess, that I had set up the views in IB. There, I added my class I was talking about, to my parent-view (sounds confusing, I know - but, hey, it's IB :)...

The goal was to have some sort of overlay-view pop up - but I didn't wanted to put that view in a separate nib-file. So, that's why I just added the class from the classes-library.

I finally gave up now and moved the overlay to a separate nib, made my class a view-controller and... everything works fine...

Thanks for the hints anyway, guys - I did learn a good bit...